# Add javascript event in DropDownList http helper ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("cssFiles", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.cssFiles, "Crear Nuevo", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "selCssFile" })
        <span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFileName" style="display:none;" placeholder="Nombre del archivo">
        </span>
</div>
```

I want to add a Javascript event for show the "txtFileName" when "Crear Nuevo" is select, and hide it when the dropdown change

Comment: You can do that with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to attach click event on your dropdown element.

**Code**

```
$('#selCssFile').on('change',function(){
   //implement code after selected the option
});
```